# Dygraph legend time-date format change to include day of week

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

Hello I am using the R `dygraphs` package, and would like to be able to change the legend time-date format to include the day of the week (i.e. "%a")

I have looked in `dyOptions` and `dyLegend` but cannot see anything that would help me with this...

Below is a simple example...but would ideally like it to be in shiny app...

```
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
dygraph(xts(rnorm(100),Sys.time()+seq(100)),main='random_graph')
```

To give a bit of additional detail...I would like the a format like: "Wed 22 Jan 2020 08:35:05" for both the axis and the legend.

Comment: I think it's not possible, because your data needs to be a xts and the format is a date.

Comment: xts can take both indexes of Date or timestamps

Answer (score 2):

It *is* possible. You need to supply the `axisLabelFormatter` parameter of `dygraphs::dyAxis` with a Javascript function that takes a date argument and returns a string based on that date. The function is just passed in as a string.

I'm not sure you can access any of the javascript libraries that dygraph imports, so to keep it simple I have included a vanilla javascript snippet that gives the date in the format I assume you wanted. It can easily be expanded or modified using the javascript functions `getYear()` `getFullYear()` `getHours()` `getMinutes()` and `getSeconds()`

```r
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)

my_js <- 'function(d)
          {
            var d = new Date(d.getTime() + 7200*1000);
            var weekday = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
            var months  = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                           "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
            var result = ""
            result += weekday[d.getDay()] + " " + d.getDate()
            result += " " + months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();
            return result;
          }'

set.seed(69)
dg <- dygraph(xts(rnorm(100), Sys.time() + seq(100)*10000), main = 'random_graph')
dyAxis(dg, name = "x", axisLabelFormatter = my_js)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great start but is there a way to get the legend to also have the day of the week included. and in addition to this..when you zoom into the graph, the axis outputs do not adjust to take into consideration the times stamps as well

Comment: There’s a ‘legendFormatter’ option within dygraph.js but the htmlwidget that is part of the dygraphs package doesn’t provide a direct R interface to it. The dygraph object is exported though, so I think you should be able to inject some Javascript using the htmlwidgets package. I’ll look into this.

Comment: Thanks, and did you have any thoughts on the zoom issue when getting different axis values for different levels of zoom?

Comment: You can access the dygraph in javascript using `htmlwidgets::onRender( dg, 'function(el, d, data) {dygraph = window.HTMLWidgets.getInstance(el).dygraph;')` which allows you to do anything you want to the underlying dygraph by just calling the dygraph.js methods directly on the dygraph object. However, it appears that the version of dygraph.js used in building the R package is an old version which pre-dates the inclusion of legendFormatter. So it would require a work-around with quite a lot of javascript to emulate the legend.

Comment: The alternative is to re-build the R package from source with the latest version of dygraph.js. It might actually be just as easy to fork the project on github, substitute the latest version  of dygraphs.js into `dygraphs/inst/htmlwidgets/lib/dygraphs` and do a `devtools::install_github`, or do the same thing on your local machine.

Comment: OK, I have had a good look at this. I was able to fork the project and update the javascript library to the latest version, but of course that led to lots of new bugs appearing in the R interface, with multiple calls to nonexistent functions that had to be patched before I could get it to draw anything. I eventually got to the point where I could put whatever I liked in the legend box, but by then there were other problems with formatting etc.and I realised this would need substantial development time.  I have [logged this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/issues/241) on GitHub..

Comment: That's annoying that there isn't a simple solution but thanks for your efforts!